# Can the Data Export Service in Microsoft Dynamics export data to an Azure Synapse Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure-sql-data-warehouse, microsoft-dynamics

I am able to use the Data Export Service (DES) to export data to an Azure SQL Database. When I try to create a new profile in DES that connects to a Data Warehouse (aka Azure Synapse Analytics) on the same Azure SQL Server using the same user (db_owner member), I keep getting the message 'Error validating profile registration'. Note that the Key Vault Secrets used for each connection are virtually the same except the 'Initial Catalog' and the DES wizard is able to validate the connection to the Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The reason is that an Azure Synapse Data Warehouse does not allow you to create user data types and DES creates data types to use in it's stored procedures that help merge the incremental data into the SQL tables.